# Linux vs Windows std::map assignment constructors (Why such a difference?)

Tags: c++, stl, constructor, copy-constructor

I was witnessing some unexpected behavior in a C++ application I am writing in Linux Ubuntu. I would construct an object with parameters and then put a copy of that object into a std::map using the assignment operator. I wrote a simple program to demonstrate this situation...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(void) : _x(0)
   {
      cout << "Default" << endl;
   }

   Foo(int a) : _x(a)
   {
      cout << "Param" << endl;
   }

   Foo(Foo const &foo) :
      _x(foo._x)
   {
      cout << "Copy" << endl;
   }

   Foo& operator=(Foo const &foo)
   {
      cout << "Assignment" << endl;

      if (this != &foo)
      {
         _x = foo._x;
      }

      return *this;
   }

   int get(void)
   {
      return _x;
   }

private:
   int _x;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
   std::map<int, Foo> foos;

   Foo a_foo(10);

   foos[100] = a_foo;

   return 0;
}
```

Here I am just printing out which constructor/operator gets called in what order so I can see how the construction and assignment works in the "main" function.

When I run this in Windows I get my expected output...

Param
Default
Assignment

When I run this in Linux I get the following output...

Param
Default
Copy
Copy
Assignment

Why are the two extra copy constructors there? It seems very inefficient to create the object so many times?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your compiler on windows did copy ellision where the compiler on linux didn't. Did you forget to turn on optimisations?

Comment: I think you need to specify compiler versions and flags.

Comment: I am using g++ 4.2. For this demonstration I have tried no optimization flag and with all compiler optimization options (-O, -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, and -Os). All produce the same result...

Comment: use an even newer version of g++. There's at least 4.8 out right now.

Comment: g++ 4.2 is really old, it came out 5 years ago. Like @NicolasLouisGuillemot suggested. Try a newer version.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to. I can't since the platform I am developing for is fixed for now. So, is that optimization just not available in 4.2 at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer lies in stl_map.h. Its behaviour depends on whether you compile with C++11 support or not. <s>If you do then the STL can take advantage of move semantics to avoid unnecessary copying.</s> VC++ uses the new language features by default but if you use g++ or clang you need to get used to using the `-std=c++0x` flag in 4.2 or `-std=c++11` in newer versions.

With `-std=c++11` set the output with g++4.8 is:

```
Param
Default
Assignment
```

**Edit:** Thank you very much for clarifying for me that my assumption that this was down to move semantics was incorrect. I'm leaving this answer in place to direct users to [this better one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694450/spurious-copies-in-c03-libstdc-vs-c11).

Comment: Unfortunately C++11 cannot be used in our platform yet (hopefully soon). I have tried compiling with many different compiler options (-O, -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, and -Os). None of them give me the efficient output. For now I will live with what it does. Thanks!

Comment: Well just so you know you are still using C++11 on Windows, it's just VC++ isn't asking your permission first to use it! 

Also no level of optimisation can give you the efficient output because it relies on a new C++11 feature, move semantics, which you should totally learn about because it is awesome and, as this example demonstrates, can make your code much more efficient. :)

Comment: I did some testing of this out of interest. Move semantics do not seem to be everything here. If you add a move ctor and assignment, they do not get called either.  Added another q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694450/move-sematics-or-copy-elision-in-map-assignment)

Comment: Please explain why move is involved here at all, or remove it from your answer.  The code above has no rvalue ctors or assignment.