# Spurious copies in c++03 libstdc++ vs c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() : _x(0) 
   {
       cout << "Default" << endl;
   }
   Foo(int a) : _x(a)
   {
      cout << "Param" << endl;
   }

   Foo(Foo const &foo) :
      _x(foo._x)
   {
      cout << "Copy" << endl;
   }

   Foo& operator=(Foo const &foo)
   {
      cout << "Assignment" << endl;
      _x = foo._x;
      return *this;
   }

   int get(void)
   {
      return _x;
   }

private:
   int _x;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
   std::map<int, Foo> foos;

   Foo a_foo(10);

   foos[100] = a_foo;

   return 0;
}
```

Compiled in gcc with -std=c++11 and you get the output,

```
Param
Default
Assignment
```

Remove -std=c++11, then you get,

```
Param
Default
Copy
Copy
Assignment
```

[with c++11](http://rextester.com/LDQJR35920)

[without](http://rextester.com/FDV96176)

[libc++ example producing the superior output in c++03 mode](http://rextester.com/KXCIE21888)

Where are the two extra copies coming from?

They are related to calling the subscript operator, not the assignment. (They remain if you remove the assignment.) To me they don't seem to be needed, even in a pre-C++11 world, as the libc++ example shows.

This was originally motivated by looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663963/linux-vs-windows-stdmap-assignment-constructors-why-such-a-difference?rq=1)

Comment: You don't get them in C++11 mode so why not remove all the rvalue-ref functions from the question entirely? The question is obviously not affected by them.

Comment: I expect this is a QoI thing inside libstdc++ and guess that it would take some doing to pointlessly determine precisely what's going on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They are there _because_ the question is not affected by them, in contradiction to the earlier answer.

Comment: It's generally a good idea, when you want to know the effect of _Variable A_, not to introduce an unnecessary and irrelevant _Variable B_.

Comment: The answer you point to is misleading at best. The `Foo` presented in that question has a user provided copy constructor & copy assignment operator, which will suppress implicit declaration of their move special member function counterparts, so `Foo` will never be moved, even in `-std=c++11` mode, which is what the answer seems to suggest is happening. Moreover, libc++ produces the same output in C++03 and C++11 modes, so it is a QoI issue. As Lightness says, to figure out what's going on will involve digging through the libstdc++ implementation.

Comment: Sure, so the earlier question is wrong.  Not sure why you have to make this question a bad question just because they got it wrong.  Include a link to the other question, mention that it is wrong and why in an appendix.  Making it central to your question just adds noise.  I get that is why you asked the question: but why is background info, not central info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [LWG 334](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#334):

The C++03 Standard mandates the following effects for `operator[]` ([lib.map.access]p1):

> **Returns:** `(*((insert(make_pair(x, T()))).first)).second`.

---

libstdc++ implements the insertion used by `operator[]` (in the case where the key doesn't exist yet) as follows in C++03 mode:

```
 __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
```

`__i` is the insertion point, it is computed as

```
iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
```

`__k` is the parameter of `operator[]`.

The creation of the temporary `value_type(__k, mapped_type())` causes the first copy (from `mapped_type()` into the `value_type` pair). The second copy is the result of `insert`, which copies the `value_type` pair into an actual node.

The original version from 1997 is:

```
return (*((insert(value_type(k, T()))).first)).second;
```

which is almost to the letter of the Standard (which didn't even exist back then!). The last time it was changed significantly was in 1998. Prior to that, it used:

```
__i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, _Tp()));
```

The commit message says this was to

> Update to SGI STL 3.11.

---

[Earlier versions of the SGI STL (1995)](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/STL/DOC.PDF) did indeed specify `map::operator[]` in the same way as the C++03 Standard:

> For a map `m` and key `k`, `m[k]` is semantically equivalent to `(*((m.insert(make_pair(k, T()))).first)).second` .

SGI STL v2.03 (1997) had already switched to using `value_type` instead of `make_pair`. And as gcc's commit log suggests, SGI STL's implementation changed again between v3.0 (also 1997) and v3.11 (1998) from `insert(value_type(..` to the form still present in libstdc++ using `lower_bound` and only creating the pair if the key doesn't exist yet.

---

So one could say that libstdc++ implements the first proposed resolution of LWG 334 (`value_type` instead of `make_pair`). This isn't exactly what happened, though, looking at its history. It's simply following [SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html). libc++ doesn't strictly conform to C++03 in this respect.

---

libstdc++'s C++11 version of the same operator uses a custom emplacement function. The C++11 Standard's specification of `map::operator[]` follows the proposed resolution of LWG 334:

> *Effects:* If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.

(where `x` is the parameter of `operator[]`)

Comment: As far as I can tell, C++03 didn't change the effects of `map::operator[]` compared to C++98.

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting and thorough. In c++11, the wording of effects seems to be what is in LWG 334.

Comment: @tahsmith Yes, I stopped a bit early there. I've included the C++11 wording now. It was also quite interesting to dig into gcc's git history! Luckily, I remembered there was some LWG issue related to `operator[]`, so finding LWG 334 wasn't too difficult.

Comment: As a small follow up do you happen to know if anything was done about the following comment in LWG 334? "We may also wish to have a blanket statement somewhere in clause 17 saying that we do not intend the semantics of sample code fragments to be interpreted as specifing exactly how many copies are made. "

Comment: @tahsmith Sorry, I don't know. I can't find anything similar in C++14's §17, though. I guess they've (currently) resolved it by making the specification of individual functions more abstract (just like `map::operator[]`).

Comment: @tahsmith See also http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#98