# Is there "modern" way to avoid this kind of code duplication

Tags: c++, c++11, dry

I have C++ class similar to this:

```
class A{
    std::string str;

public:
    A(std::string &str) : str(str){}

    int cmpAt(const std::string &key) const{
        return str.cmp(key);
    }

    int cmpAt(const char *key) const{
        return str.cmp(key);
    }
}
```

Both `cmpAt` methods look the same. Is there some way NOT to duplicate the method? Perhaps with `template` ?

Comment: Why do you need both?

Comment: You don't need to define both methods. Define the `const std::string&` only.

Comment: Why not just stick to the first method? Legacy reasons?

Comment: I guess he doesn't want the overhead of constructing a `std::string` when he calls it with `char*`.

Comment: Is mostly premature optimization :) , but sometimes `const char *` could be very long

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just write a function template:

```
template <typename K>
int cmpAt(K const& key) const {
    return str.compare(key);
}
```

That way, if you call `cmpAt` with a `const char*`, you can avoid the overhead of having to construct an extra `std::string`.

---

**EDIT** Never mind, you're out of luck:

> ```
> int compare(const charT* s) const;
> ```
>
> 5 *Returns:* `compare(basic_string(s))`.

So just delete the `const char*` overload - it provides you nothing of extra value over the `std::string const&` overload. You would have to write your own `compare` function to avoid the extra `string` constructor, at which point it's not code duplication anymore.

Comment: Neither libstdc++ nor libc++ implement it in this way, though. Probably a defect in the string specs, or the allocation isn't intended to be observable. Both use `char_traits::compare`.

Comment: can you give me link where you found the compare() source?

Comment: @Nick That's in the C++ standard.

Comment: @dyp Standard defect? Good for the two libraries to not follow the standard in this case...

Comment: @Barry Yes that's what I think. Reminds me of the STL spec for [`map::operator[]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30700105/). --> http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html

Comment: @Nick Since `basic_string` is part of the C++ Standard Library, there is no single *source* (code) of the `compare` function, but several implementations of a function whose behaviour is specified by the C++ Standard. For example, [libc++'s implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/string#L3703) -- [libstdc++'s implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc#L1394)

Comment: @dyp how would you observe that allocation?  I don't beleive that std::string is mandated to do any allocation when constructed from a character pointer.  Now, in practice, SSO usually only occurs for small strings, but under the standard eliminating the allocation on even a huge string should be legal, no?

Comment: @Yakk Well I was first and foremost thinking about custom allocators indeed. But it might be possible to replace the default `operator new` to make it observable; or use a character type with some overloaded `operator new`. With the relaxed allocation rules, it might be possible that another allocation is extended, but that should still be observable. -- Edit: Ah, you're talking about *not observing the allocation is not a proof of non-compliance*? (oops, three negatives)

Comment: @Yakk You're probably right: The spec of `string`'s ctors is very vague, and doesn't really talk about allocations. It does use the formulation "allocated copy", which might be a (very minor) defect, though.

Comment: @Yakk The default construction and storage of a custom allocator is observable, though, even under SSO. (Not to mention that the spec of `compare` makes it impossible to use allocators which cannot be default-constructed.)

Answer (score 5):

I would use `boost::string_ref` or your favourite other implementation of it

```
class A{
    std::string str;

public:
    A(std::string &str) : str(str){}

    int cmpAt(const boost::string_ref &key) const{
        return key.compare(str) * -1;
    }
}
```

This will not create temporary strings and you can pass string literals and `std::string`.

Answer (score 4):

When `int cmpAt(const std::string &key)` is called with `const char*`, key will be constructed with `const char*`. so you can simply delete `cmpAt(const char *key)`.

Comment: Constructing std::string over and over again is a big waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have correctly pointed out, in your specific case, there's no need for a non-`const` comparison function.

However, in the general case, you can do the following:

```
RetType someMethod(params...) const {
    return LongAndComplexComputation(params, ...);
}

// Return type deduction is C++14.
// If you can't use C++14, only C++11, the return type should be:
// const std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type *
auto cthis() const {
    return this;
}

RetType someMethod(params...) {
    return cthis()->someMethod(params, ...)
}
```

If necessary, you will have to cast away `const`-qualification from the return type (e.g. when you are returning a pointer inside `*this`), using `const_cast`.